# Не компилируется код CodeBlocks 13.12 g++ на xubuntu

Tags: c, gcc, компиляция, g++, codeblocks

Стандартно создал проект, открылся шаблон Хелло Ворлд:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
  
int main()
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

На убунте щикарно все компилируется и запускается, а тут выдает ошибку:

> g++  -o Pr5 .objs/main.o
> g++: error: .objs/main.o: Нет такого файла или каталога
>
> g++: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
> 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: Проверил сегодня из терминала: компиляция происходит верно и на gcc, и на g++. Исполняемые файлы запускаются. Но как настроить компиляцию и запуск в codeblocks?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря сначала нужно выполнить комманду

```
g++ .../main.cpp -o .objs/main.o
```

Точку в начале имени каталога .objs ставит CodeBlocks?